# Python : libsvm import svmutil error

Tags: python, libsvm

Used libsvm on python and want to import svmutil, but i get some error!!

---

I try two ways from those code

First, If I used python GUI shell to enter the command line by line, it will not cause an error,

```
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir('D:\libsvm-3.20\python')
>>> import svmutil
>>> svmutil
<module 'svmutil' from 'D:\\libsvm-3.20\\python\\svmutil.py'>
```

---

Second, If I write a script(xxxx.py) and execution python script, it will cause an error

xxxx.py:

```
import os
os.chdir('D:\libsvm-3.20\python')
from svmutil import *
```

error:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python34\svm\crossvaildation.py", line 6, in <module>
    from svmutil import *
ImportError: No module named 'svmutil'
>>>
```

---

I do not know where wrong, please give me some advice!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use "sys.path.append('thatdirectory')" then import

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Add the line:
sys.path.append ('D: \ libsvm-3.20 \ python')
And executed correctly!